# jsp insert time in database

Tags: database, jsp

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO discussion(section_id, weekday, room, mandatory, starttime,endtime)
     VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
     pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("SECTION_ID")));                                        
pstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("WEEKDAY"));
pstmt.setString(3, request.getParameter("ROOM"));
pstmt.setString(4, request.getParameter("MANDATORY")); 
pstmt.setString(5, request.getParameter("starttime")); 
pstmt.setString(6, request.getParameter("endtime"));
```

right now I set the starttime and endtime in database as time without timezone type
if I use setTime to get the endtime and startime. how to modify this code
I didn't use any class here. I don't think I can use method here
the data is from user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your dateString intered by user is in format dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Then you can use setDate like this

```
private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";
public static final SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());

pstmt.setTime(5,new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("starttime")).getTime()));
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I got this error when compile    Illegal modifier for the variable TIME_FORMAT; only final is permitted

Comment: user input like 9:00 hh:mm:ss

Comment: this way I found from other post while it can insert into database but it insert the current time not user input.  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                        long t = date.getTime();
                        
                        java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(t);
                        pstmt.setTime(5, sqlTime);
                        pstmt.setTime(6, sqlTime);

Comment: Are you keeping this TIME_FORMAT variable inside the method?
either keep it as a member variable or if you are keeping it in method scope then reove private modifier

Comment: If you have input like 9:00 then make TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm";

Comment: I remove the public and static those words

Comment: but when I try to click run and insert value it shows null and the data cannot insert

Comment: I try 9:00:00 also, but it still show null and data cannot insert

Comment: are you sure you are getting value in parameter starttime just double check it

Comment: what do you mean getting value in starttime?

Comment: i mean just check if request.getParameter("starttieme") is giving you back something or it is giving null.

Comment: here is working code to parse time. public class TimeParser{
 private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm";
 public static final SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
 public static void main(String[] args){
  try{
   Time t = new Time(timeFormat.parse("1:16").getTime());
   System.out.println(t.toString());
  }catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}

Comment: pstmt.setString(5, request.getParameter("starttime"));
                        pstmt.setString(6, request.getParameter("endtime"));  I set like this way, insert like 900 it does can insert into database

Comment: You mean the value of starttime parameter is 900 then it won't work it will throw parse exception value should be like 9:00 then only it will work

Comment: no, when I use your method, I insert 9:00 it doesn't work. I test the starttime whether can get data so I change the code to string type, the connection with database is fine.

Comment: String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm"; 
                        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()); 
                           
                        pstmt.setTime(5, new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("starttime")).getTime()));
                        pstmt.setTime(6, new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endtime")).getTime())); Now the code like this, it still cannot insert into database. starttime and endtime database type now is time without timezone

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error. Not working is not enough to know why it is not working.try debugging to see what went wrong you can check the code which i posted in the comment TimeParser class this does the job of parsing time from string for time parsing now all you have to do is refine the code to suit your requiremnet. and if any problem give the exception or error you are getting

Comment: as long as I submit the form. the html page didn't show the table. just show null this word

Comment: update your question with full code for form on jsp which you are submitting and the full code for servlet method get or post whichever you are writing your code in

Comment: Hi, somehow I cannot add full code here. here is the github link  https://github.com/BTC2014/project/blob/master/WebContent/discussion.jsp

Comment: I can see only one jsp over there how you are accessing this jsp, if directly with url then please send the url or if you are going there from other jsp then post the code for the other jsp also

Comment: now only run it in eclipse now. so only this jsp file and a database table named discussion. other file is unrelated to this jsp

Comment: That's the problem in jsp you are accessing request parameter values but before coming to the jsp you haven't set any value to those request parameter so obviosly it will give you null.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/132b/discussions.jsp I run this jsp file on a servlet and input the data in the form. I did get the value to those parameters

Comment: I tried. but when I submit the form it give me null. String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm"; SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()); out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("starttime") ); out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("WEEKDAY") ); pstmt.setTime(5, new time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("starttime")).getTime()));pstmt.setTime(6, new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endtime")).getTime()));  when I run this, it can give me result like Items: null Items: MONDAY null  so the starttime method is wrong

Comment: I think the problem the getparameter cannot get time from input. how to fix this?

Comment: just check the name attribute of the input it should have value starttime like <input name="starttime"/>

Answer (score 0):

**1.you should this method:**

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;

pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (starttime,endtime)VALUES(?,?)");
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime));
pstmt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

**sample:**

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (col_name)VALUES(?)");
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

**2.Another one interesting answer:**

*You can use SimpleDateFormat to parse a String in the given pattern to a java.util.Date object.*

Assuming that it's HH:mm, then you can do so:

```
String time = request.getParameter("time");
Date date = null;

try 
{
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time);
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    request.setAttribute("time_error", "Please enter time in format HH:mm");
}
```

Once having the `java.util.Date object`, you can store it in a TIME column by converting it to `java.sql.Time and using PreparedStatement#setTime()`.

```
PreparedStatement pt;
pt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (columname) VALUES (?)");
pt.setTime(1, new Time(date.getTime()));
pt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: you method first one only insert the current time not user input time

Comment: @user3382017, you should use the 2 method.

Comment: I tried. but when I submit the form it give me null. String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm"; SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()); out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("starttime") ); out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("WEEKDAY") ); pstmt.setTime(5, new time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("starttime")).getTime()));pstmt.setTime(6, new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endtime")).getTime()));  when I run this, it can give me result like Items: null Items: MONDAY null  so the starttime method is wrong

Comment: you must put code in your post, i thing your doing some mistake. use the edit button to post your code.

Comment: https://github.com/BTC2014/project/blob/master/WebContent/discussion.jsp    Somehow i cannot add full code pasted here

Comment: I think the problem the getparameter cannot get time from input. how to fix this?